# Blazor Server AWS Cognito Hosted UI

Tags: blazor, amazon-cognito, blazor-server-side

I am trying to setup the hosted version of AWS Cognito with my Blazor Server app (NOT WASM). I am successfully redirecting to the aws login and get a callback to my app with a `id_token` in the url.

I am using `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` and `<AuthorizeView>` and also `@attribute [Authorize]` on my razor pages. But I am never successfully logged in.

So my question is do I need to handle the callback myself and authorize the user somehow or should this be taken care of by configuration in the program.cs with something like this?

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
    {
        opt.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
        opt.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opt =>
    {
     ...
    });
```

I already spent days on this and find so many different but not clear tutorials online.

Comment: You can follow this blog and try to do similar for Blazor. I wrote this for ASP.NET Core MVC - https://coderjony.com/blogs/authenticating-users-in-aspnet-core-mvc-using-amazon-cognito

Comment: @AnkushJain I did it exactly like in your blog, unfortanley it doesn't work. I also get no errors. Are you sure I do not need to handle the id_token myself?